How to handle 3d input data with tree boosting models for multi-output regression?
I have data of the form 32 commodities x 27 features x 3000 time steps for stock forecasting. For some reason, I must use a variety of tree boosting models (lightgbm, xgboost, adaboost) to compare performance on a regression task: predicting return rates of each individual stock at a singular timestep with training on a sample of previous timesteps. The intended dataflow would be: model trained on n timesteps, output a vector of return rates for each commodity (32 element vector) at a single timestep say t+2. However, I am not sure how to structure the data for effective training.
Right now, I flatten the data along the commodity and feature dimensions to create a 3000x864 dataframe, but I dont think this is the way to go as I suspect I am losing some information.
I use the MultiOutputRegressor from sklearn to adapt lgbm, but the mse is around 0.5, very bad for predicting values normalized between -1 and 1, considering that the data contains a number of 0s which are easy to predict.
Is this flattening method the correct way to handle 3d data or do I need to use another approach?
